# using array map when some data is optional

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a JSON message with list of properties coming in as part of a http request. Some of those object properties I want to preprocess. However, they are not all required and can be non-existent in the inbound JSON.

My first though was to use an array and the "map" method to apply the preprocessing function:

```
function preprocess(event) {


  var build_map = [
        {type: builder.concat, newPropertyName :"modified.URL", data: [event.site, event.slug]},
        {type: builder.removeExtraSpaces, newPropertyName :"modified.name", data: [event.firstName, event.middleName, event.lastName]},
        {type: builder.cleanEmail, newPropertyName :"modified.email", data: event.email}
    ];

build_map.map(function(item){
    var type = item.type,
        fieldName = item.fieldName,
        data = item.data;

    calc(type, fieldName, data, function(err, str){
        //do stuff
    })

});
}
```

But in some cases the inbound event doesn't contain all the properties set in the array.  I.e. using the example above the  "event" could be missing the [event.site, event.slug] and look like:

```
var testEvent = {
firstName: "bob",
lastName: "smith",
email: "a@example.com"
};
```

This causes an error since "event.site" is undefined.   I know I can create a reference object or array, loop through to check if each property is in "event" set before dynamically creating the "build_map" array....but I'm wondering if there is a better approach or JavaScript built-in that I should be using in place of "map" or "forEach".  I'm assuming there is some design pattern applied commonly to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is more a theoretical question I would answer by saying following functional patterns of handling data in JS (React, Redux, Rx, Elm, Cycle, etc), you should not mutate data by adding events to it in the future.

You should have a function somewhere that takes input (a JSON message) and procs an event.

If you get the JSON and must bind events to it like that, build a separate collection for those. This way you cant break the original state of the messages. Its really hard to give a specific answer to your case as I do not have more info on this event object. For example:

```
//ES6 syntax 
build_map
.map(x => Object.assign({},x)) //Create a copy
.map(x => {x.event = undefined; return x}) //set event so we dont crash
.forEach(x => { /*do stuff*/})
```